# What directory (if any) should I use to store settings file for my add-in?

Tags: c#, file, io, outlook-addin

I've developed an add-in and now I'd like to enable it to store/retrieve settings upon the launch of Outlook. I've checked the current working directory using `Environment.CurrentDirectory` but when I tried to `File.WriteAllText` to it, I failed due to access rights. So, my question is twofold.

1. Will any directory suffice or is there a recommended one?
2. Do I need to store the settings in a local file or is there a neater method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the `Environment` class as follows.

```
String dir = Environment.GetFolderPath(
  Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
```

A bit lengthy syntax but it does the job well. Not sure if you'll have full access rights from an add-in, though. Also, It'd be good to know if somebody will suggest a better storage method. Once I used a web service until I discovered that my user often will do his job while sitting on the train (read: off-line). It worked unless he didn't reboot his machine before getting on board.